# Short exact sequence in nonabelian group cohomology and finitness condition

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $1\to A\to B\to C\to 1$ be an exact sequence of (nonabelian) $G$-groups. Then there is a well-known exact sequence of pointed sets

$
1\to A^G\to B^G\to C^G\to H^1(G,A)\to H^1(G,B)\to H^1(G,C)
$

In Serre's "Galois cohomology" it is claimed (Sec. 5.5) that in order to $H^1(G,B)$ being finite it is sufficient that $H^1(G,C)$ is finite and $Im(H^1(G,A_b)\to H^1(G,B_b))$ are finite for all $b\in Z^1(G,B)$, where $A_b$ is the twisted $G$-group $A$ (defined by the new action $g*a=b_gg\cdot ab_g^{-1})$.

So, my question is: can one show an example when the condition that $H^1(G,A)$ and $H^1(G,C)$ are finite is not sufficient for $H^1(G,B)$ being finite?